# kerberos instead of http over ssl

Tags: security, ssl, http, https, kerberos

If I want to use kerberos instead of https (http over ssl) how do I make sure data is not tampered or read in the transit?

Comment: Generally, you use both SSL *and* Kerberos to put an extra layer of security (SSL) over the Kerberos ticket exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a false premise, but your question can be answered.

Encrypt the data. You can use secret-key encryption or public-key encryption (usually in conjunction with secret-key encryption - for non trivial amounts of data). Plus a **secure** method of key exchange.

Generally it is better to use a well tested solution (e.g. HTTPS or SSH) than try to create your own solution.

Comment: Probably I was looking for something like this http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-tls-kerb-cipher-suites-00 . But I guess this did not go well beyond a draft. I will stick with existing methods. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're barking up the wrong tree. Kerberos is exclusively an authentication mechanism - it is as much use for the purposes you suggest as a banana.

Why do you want to use HTTPS?

Comment: In fact, it is possible to use Kerberos session keys for encrypting traffic. LDAP does this, as did Telnet long ago.